# Is it possible to implement a container that can hold POD element and initialized in compile time allocated static storages?

Tags: c++

For example, an object like map which contain 20000 entries. Without calling insert method during runtime, initialize its element at compile time, and write this map into binary file, just like a global int array.

Comment: Yes, beyond any reasonable doubt it's possible. Whether it's a good idea is a whole separate question though.

Comment: What I've done in the past with C and would probably do again rather than fight templates and constexpr is write a script in Perl to read in the map data and write out a C file containing the data structure as an array.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you've asked a lot of questions without [accepting one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If your problem has been solved, please tick the symbol beside the question that helps

Answer (score 5):

Compile time: **No**
Without using runtime `map::insert()`: **Yes**

With C++11, you may declare and initialize a global object.

```
#include<map>
std::map<int, int> m = {{0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}};
int main () {}
```

Inside some global object constructor you may write down this `map` into a file.

```
struct Global {
  Global (const char* fileName) {
    std::ofstream file(fileName);
    for(auto pair : m)
      // insert operation
  }
}
g_Initialize("xyz.txt");
```

Hence you have things ready before `main()` runs.

While doing this, beware of [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html).

**Update**: `std::map` is just a handy example. The key here is to use [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). You may use a custom class as well.

Comment: If he'd asked about standard containers, your answer would be spot-on. He seems to be asking about whether *he* could implement a container that was initialized entirely at compile time though--and that he certainly can do.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, Agree. But OP uses keywords "like" *`map`* and `insert` in the question. I assume that while asking the question OP might be unaware of this C++11 feature which already facilitates what is required. Even with customer containers same rules apply. The key here is the new *initializer list*.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question you asked in the title, "Yes probably."

See what you can do with `constexpr` and templates. As for writing it into a binary file, that is tougher. If you want it to be useful it will have to not use any pointers. But then, it probably couldn't use any dynamic memory allocation or pointers anyway. Not and stay `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map` is just an ordered collection of pairs, and a structure *like* that, that you can initialize at compile time, is just the same.

Disregarding the sorted property you can you just declare an array with initializer, and hope that you don't run up against one of the implementation limits.

Guaranteeing that the thing is sorted, at compile time, is where it starts getting complicated and possibly not really doable in practice. But I somehow doubt that this is part of your requirements. I think the “like” and exemplification was probably not intentionally meant to include this, and if so, well, you have your work cut out: technically it's trivial, but doing it, writing those thousands upon thousands of lines, and finally checking if you're within implementation limits on static array size, etc., will be trying your patience.